# Pandas read_sql_query validation

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, pandas

How does `pandas` verify the SQL query that is passed to `pandas.read_sql_query`? For example, the following does not work.

```
$ echo 1 > test.txt
$ python
>>> from pandas import read_sql_query
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> db = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
>>> read_sql_query(".shell rm test.txt", db)
[Traceback omitted]
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near ".": syntax error [SQL: '.shell rm test.txt']
```

However, if I run that same query directly in `sqlite3`, then it runs correctly and `test.txt` is removed.

This implies that `pandas.read_sql_query` is stricter about what SQL statements it processes, but I cannot locate what restrictions are imposed. I would like to verify that is safe to allow a user to pass in an arbitrary query string to a program and guarantee that only the database will affected.

Comment: I believe it's because '.shell rm test.txt' is not SQL, but rather a command that only the sqlite3 process knows how to use. It would be quite scary if arbitrary SQL could remove files on disk!

Comment: Yes, but the statement is executed within the SQLite engine even when wrapped by Pandas. So Pandas could execute that statement if it wanted to I think.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. It's probably a wrapper over the C-style SQLite API which has no knowledge of the utility provided by the sqlite3 executable. The docs (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html) also mention that the first parameter is a 'string SQL query', which that command most certainly is *not*. Given that it barfs on the first '.', and all the sqlite helper functions start with a '.', I would bet you really can't run these commands like this.